# In Django 3.0.3 I get an integrity error, unique constraint failed using foreignkey

Tags: python, django

I am still learning Django but can't find a solution for my simple app, I would really appreciate some help. Thanks!

Link for traceback: http://dpaste.com/1H1ERWJ

This is the code for model.py file.

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.utils import timezone
    from django.urls import reverse
    from django.conf import settings

    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

    User = get_user_model()

    class Lot(models.Model):
        #use User class from django
        user = models.ForeignKey(User,db_column='user',related_name='lots',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        price = models.IntegerField()
        size = models.IntegerField()
        description = models.TextField()

        def __str__(self):
            return self.message

        def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
            super().save(*args,**kwargs)

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('pb:new',kwargs={'username':self.user.username,'pk':self.pk})

        class Meta:
            ordering = ['-created_at']
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback

Comment: why `db_column='user'` and not the primary key? Removing this will likely fix the issue

Comment: Code actually looks fine. When exactly do you get the error? Suggestion for edit - add the context (is it while generating the migration, or is it while inserting the data). Secondly, add the full traceback.

Comment: Removed db_column='user' but still not working. Problem happens when I insert the data.

Comment: Link for traceback: http://dpaste.com/1H1ERWJ

Comment: It says you are getting an `OperationalError`. You might need to clean your database after making the change suggested by Marat.

Answer (score 0):

I changed db_column='user' to db_column='user_id' and it worked. This was not necessary in Django 1 but in Django 3 it is.